# Replace quotes to double quotes for alt attribute

Tags: php, regex

what reg expression can replace this wrong alts with single quotes alt='something's face' with this alt="something's face"
please help

PS i have many pages with html content with such wrong alts in images
so i need replace all alts. some alts have quote in it (alt='something's face') some alts do not have (alt='something face'), but all alts have view alt='something' and i need convert them to alt="some text"

Comment: but i have html contents for these pages already in database

Comment: Oh then at the time of saving you have to do that. But never the less you will get some solution.Stay here

Comment: view-source:https://hdlava.me/name/aleksandra-daddario.html

Comment: <img src='/foto/content/00/01/19/42/lerman-i-daddario.jpg' class="alignleft" width=300 height=390 alt='Логан Лерман и Александра Даддарио' title='Логан и Александра' />

Comment: <img src='/foto/content/00/01/19/42/prezentatsiya-womens-health.jpg'width=300 height=300 alt='На презентации Women's hеаlth' title='Women's hеаlth' />

Comment: its ok for regular html but i am creating also amp pages and its a critical error for them

Comment: you can write your alt like this : `alt='Something\'s face'`. you can match an alt with this `alt='[^']*'`

Comment: $html = preg_replace("/alt='[^']*'/", 'alt="$1"', $html);  thats ok?? its not working ((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is, how do we tell the `'` quote used in `something's face` apart from a delimiter quote.

I suggest this :

```
alt='(.*?)'\s+
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sb2TSB/1).

Here, I'm matching the attribute's content in a lazy way until the next `'` followed by at least one space. This is assuming that a `'` quote inside the text will always be followed directly by a non-space character. The problem is, this will fail with a `'s` possession with a plural noun. For example :

```
alt='I was at my parents' house'
```

But in this case, I don't know how we're supposed to tell the quotes apart.

Answer (score 1):

As for a general purpose pattern (not just `alt` attribute values), you can use this:

[Pattern & Replacement Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/dyMPOq/1)

Test String:

```
<img src='/foto/content/00/01/19/42/prezentatsiya-womens-health.pg'width=300 height=300 alt='На презентации Women's hеаlth' title='Women's hеаlth' data-info='These are the parents' concerns'/>
```

Pattern: `~[^=]\K'(?!/>| ?[\w-]+=)~`

Replacement: `\\'`

Explanation:

For the record, my pattern proves to be successful versus `alt='I was at my parents' house'`.

Target single quotes that are not preceded by `=` AND are not followed by `/>` or another attribute declaration.  I have made it possible for no spacing between attributes, because in your sample input `width=300` is smashed into the back of the `src` value.

The `\K` just means "start the fullstring match here".  This technique is used to avoid using a capture group and this improves pattern performance.

---

Or if you want to work it the opposite way, you can convert the outer single quotes to double quotes -- but then you might need to search for any pre-existing double quotes.

`~[\w-]+=\K'|'(?=/>| ?[\w-]+=)~`  [Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/dyMPOq/3)